# "{Property} was made unavailable in iOS" in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Several properties, for example in UNMutableNotificationContent, have been flagged with this warning:

> [PropertyName] was made unavailable in iOS.

even though these are supported and no such warning is shown on the documentation of the [Xamarin.iOS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/usernotifications.unmutablenotificationcontent?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

I tried to find some information on what this warning means, but without success. Anyone got an explanation what it's about?

This is my code for example:

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent
{
   Title = "Title",
   Body = "You have 2 tasks for today.",
   Sound = UNNotificationSound.Default
};
```

Every property is marked with this warning for me. (e.g. '"Sound" was made unavailable in iOS.')

Comment: This might be related to the bug https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6371

Comment: @KenWhite that is not true. Nothing on Apple's developer site suggest that these properties have been deprecated.

Comment: @Saamer I saw that bug post, but it is about watchOS properties being labelled as iOS properties, isn't it?

Comment: The link I shared shows another class also incorrectly showing the warning. Since its just a warning, that means the page still works right? You could ignore it if you like. If you don't want to, I would recommend opening an issue in github or messaging the Xamarin iOS gitter about it